# How to say 24 of book titles?

Tags: single-word-requests

I would like to say 24 of this book title but i'm not sure if it's grammatically correct.

For example, I have a book titled "Lord of the ring". How would I say I want 20 of that in a letter.

Is it correct if I use "20 books of Lord of the ring"?

Comment: 20 ***copies*** of *Lord of the Rings*.

Comment: Just to expand on Andrew's (correct) comment - "20 books" would normally refer to 20 completely **different** books, ie 20 different titles.

Comment: You want 20 of the titles, or 20 of the books?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you are suggesting you would like 20 physical copies of the book. I also think that you are talking about "The Lord of the Rings", not "Lord of the Ring". My answer changes if you do mean "Lord of the Ring".

Here's how I would say that I would like 20 copies of the book, "The Lord of the Rings":

> 20 copies of "The Lord of the Rings".

If the book title wasn't easily recognizable as a title, then I would add in "the book" to my sentence:

> 20 copies of the book "Lord of the Ring"